# How do you configure Pi to automatically connect to nearest network?

Tags: networking, wifi

Is it possible to configure the Raspberry Pi to connect to nearest open network?
I like to take advantage of the Pi's size and SSH, but I have to use a monitor or Ethernet cord to connect to the same network.

How do you configure Pi to automatically connect to nearest network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the RPi connect to open networks with some adjustments in */etc/network/interfaces*

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and in */etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf*

```
network={
   key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

With this, the RPi will connect to Open WiFis automatically.

If you want to connect to the "nearest" network, you should write a small script. With `iwlist wlan0 scan` you get a list of Wifis an its signal level. You can select which are

1. open networks, means no WEP or WPA
2. best dBM level
   this ESSID you can use with `iwconfig wlan0 essid $bestwifi`.