# Prevent automatic connection to open wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-2, access-point, wpa-supplicant

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 with a USB wifi adapter (headless setup). The `wpa_supplicant.conf` file contains authentication information only for my wifi access point, and the pi connects to it as expected. But I don't really know what would happen if my access point is down and there are other open wifi networks available nearby? Will the pi-

**A.** automatically connect to an available open wifi network?

or

**B.** do nothing, stay disconnected and only connect to my access point once it is back?

I am trying to avoid option **A** and I prefer option **B**. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> ***A.** automatically connect to an available open wifi network?*

**wpa_supplicant** will only connect to networks that are specified in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. To connect to an open WiFi network you have to set this in wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
network={
   key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

Then wpa_supplicant will automatically connect to the open WiFi network.

> ***B.** do nothing, stay disconnected and only connect to my access point once it is back?*

If the network block, as shown above, is not in the *wpa_supplicant.conf*, it will do nothing. If you have the network block for your protected WiFi network available then the RasPi will connect to it as usual.

> *I am trying to avoid option A and I prefer option B. What can I do?*

Just don't add the network block for an open network to *wpa_supplicant.conf*.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so posting here.
I believe the discussion [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63916/how-do-you-configure-pi-to-automatically-connect-to-nearest-network) answer your question (B).

Hence, marking this question as duplicate seems reasonable.